# A proper way to log and display error details?

Tags: android, exception

I am aware that using `printStackTrace()` in Android apps should be avoided and we should use `Log` class.

Following this, I tried to log errors like this:

```
try {
   //do something  
} catch (Exception e) {
   Log.d(TAG, "General Exception:\n", e);
}
```

and I got output like this:

```
Log level: Verbose
12-27 17:20:21.468: DEBUG/MyApp Page two fragment(11193): General IOException:
```

I did not get details on `IOException`.

Can somebody advise what I am doing wrong?!

Comment: use `e.toString()` in the `catch(...){ }` block!

Comment: @t0mm13b What is then the purpose of the 3rd parameter in this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do this instead:

```
  Log.d(TAG, e.getClass().getSimpleName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize you were talking about 2 parameters method. What is then the purpose of the 3rd parameter in this method?

Comment: You can use this `d(String tag, String msg)` if you just want to print the exception message and this `d(String tag, String msg, Throwable tr)` if you want to provide the Throwable object for logging purposes.

Comment: @theMarceloR explanation is exact. You'll more often will use the 2 parameters method.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>There is no 3rd parameter!</strike>

If you **read** the sdk docs, [android.utils.Log](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) takes two parameters, this is general guideline as used:

1. a tag identifying the message (can be usually defined as `public static final String TAG="myActivity";`
2. A message, notice that this is a string so in your case it would need to be like this:

```
try {
   //do something  
} catch (Exception e) {
   Log.d(TAG, "General Exception:\n" + e);
}
```

Notice the usage of the string concatenation operator.

***Edit:*** To note: Log does have an overload which can indeed take the third parameter, but generally the method with two parameters is used, in respect to the third parameter, that is a `Throwable` as documented in the [SDK](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Throwable.html). I rarely use it in my projects nonetheless as the method with two parameters is sufficient enough for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the generic Exception, a top-level object, avoid Pokemon exception handling (gotta catch 'em all) and catch the specific exceptions. But that's not the reason you are not seeing the exception details: try `ioe.getMessage()`:

```
   try{
       startActivity( alertIntent );
   }catch(IOException ioe)
   {
       Log.e("error", "startActivity exception "+ ioe.getMessage());
   }
```

If you need to know the signature of the logging methods, just check the documentation:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html

For more details and ideas:
http://blog.nelsondev.net/?p=187

Comment: this was just a sample that's why I put general exception :). in my own case I have many more exceptions like, io, timeout, null pointer, etc., but I wanted to make this less complicated to read. ;)

Comment: I would place a breakpoint and debug it, check the Exception object and check what it has to offer about the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

```
Log.v(); // Verbose
Log.d(); // Debug
Log.i(); // Info
Log.w(); // Warning
Log.e(); // Error
```

for more i[nfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html)

```
Log.e("error", String.valueOf(e.getMessage()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Do these instead::

```
try {
 //do something  
    } 
catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "General Exception::"+e);
    }
```

Comment: Why should he do this over `Log.d`?

Comment: @afuzzyllama It does not matter. You decide on this as a developer. I usually use Log.d all the time thou we can separate logs in more complex projects.

Comment: @afuzzyllama Based on the filtering of logs you insert in it's category wise or using TAG filter on the basis on method or class name via getClassName();